# Object serialization in JSON with different element name base on the type

Tags: java, json, serialization, annotations

I wanted to change the name of xmlElement annotation based on the type of T.
For examples, if T is type of Foo then I want to set the name as foos but if T is type of Var then I want to name it as vars. 
Is it possible to do this?
Thanks in advance.

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class GenericLookupResponse<T> {

    @XmlElement(name="foos")
    private List<T> result;

    public List<T> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<T> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

response; T is Foo

```
{"foos":[{"id":dummy},{"id":dummy2}]}
```

response; T is Var

```
{"vars":[{"id":dummy},{"id":dummy2}]}
```

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545149/jaxb-polymorphism-with-generics and see if it helps.

Comment: Also refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html , if it is a possibility for you